# CS1001 Web Site Identifier expected

Tags: c#, asp.net

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: System.Web.HttpCookie the type of object , no
>   known mapping between a managed provider of local species.

```
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString);

    string sorgu = "INSERT INTO Enerji_Basvuru (sehir, tip) VALUES (@County, @type)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sorgu, cnn);
    cnn.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@County", Request.Cookies["il"]); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", Request.Cookies["AboneGrubu"].);


    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cnn.Close();
```

Comment: On a side note, you need to wrap your `cnn` and `cmd` variables into a `using` statement to ensure they get disposed property, or implement the try/catch/finally pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering both `@County` and `@type` are `varchar`; you are actually passing `HttpCookie` type to those parameter. You need to use the `Value` property of the `HttpCookie` like

```
Request.Cookies["il"].Value
```

Your SqlParameter binding should look like

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@County", Request.Cookies["il"].Value); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", Request.Cookies["AboneGrubu"].Value);
```